# Using secret as IV

Tags: security, encryption, cryptography, initialization-vector

I have an application where sensitive data needs to be encrypted in a manner where every run produces the same encrypted values from the same inputs. The primary data type is email addresses. The encrypted values need to always be the same because they are matched for statistical analysis. Runs that produce the data will occur at regular intervals over long periods of time. This makes the choice of IV for AES encryption a bit tricky. The question is: is it acceptable to use the secret (the hash of a given password) also as the IV? Would encryption modes or padding render this insecure? I'm assuming this would not be good practice since I have never seen it suggested before, but since it would be very convenient I figured I would ask.

(Note that hashing the values is already an option in the tool. Encryption is now also being considered because the values are reversable, which makes report analysis by the customer a bit simpler.)

Comment: Depends on the mode of operation how insecure this will be

Comment: Is there a mode in which it would be secure?

Comment: Sure, SIV mode and possibly others, but depending on your thread model, CBC mode might be enough.

Comment: The tool is so far single threaded. But if i had a separate cipher for each thread would that be sufficient?

Comment: Whether it's single-threaded or multi-threaded doesn't make a difference from a security aspect.

Comment: Did you mean "threat model", instead of "thread model"? I was wondering what that had to do with it.

Comment: Yes, I did. Sorry. -.-

Comment: Got it. Thanks Artjom B.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No this is not a good option. Especially with email addresses there is a big chance that the ciphertext will be partly identical if you do. This will leak information, for instance you can easily guess names or server addressed once those are repeated.

If you really require deterministic encryption they you could use AES in *Synhetic* IV (SIV) mode. That will create a ciphertext where each bit of output is completely dependent on *every* bit of the input. Alternatively, if space is sparse, it is possible to use Format Preserving Encryption (FPE).

---

I certainly hope that you use password hashing (e.g. bcrypt, scrypt, PBKDF2 or Argon2) to derive the key, otherwise your keys may not be as secure as you may think.

Comment: Leaking due to repeated domains is a good point. What if the username and domain were separated and encrypted individually? Would this be sufficient?

Comment: No that would make it worse; then identical usenames and domain names will certainly be distinguishable as the domain names would always start at the same position (0).

Comment: Not sure i understand that. I mean like this: <enc_user>@<enc_domain>.

Comment: So now you can distinguish `enc_user` regardless of the domain and the other way around.  So the data gets less random and leaks more info.

Answer (score -1):

You need to have the same IV for the same data.  Having a constant IV for all data is insecure, so you are going to have to derive the IV from the plaintext data.

Using a hash of the password would also give a fixed IV.

I would suggest using a hash of the first 16 (or whatever) bytes of the plaintext.  You might want to add some fixed extra bytes as well before hashing.

Obviously you will need to store the IV with the cyphertext if you want to be able to decrypt the data.

Since the IV is derived from the plaintext (and possibly some additional fixed bytes) then identical plaintexts will result in identical IVs.  Either prepending or appending the IV to the cyphertext will still result in identical outputs for identical inputs.

Comment: This would satisfy the requirement, but if i would need to store the IV with the encrypted text why not just use a random IV?

Comment: If you use a random IV then you will need to check if a new entry matches an existing entry, and duplicate the IV from the old entry.  Deriving the IV from the plaintext means you do not have to search the entire database (possibly decrypting every entry) before adding a new entry.  Identical plaintexts will automatically give you identical IVs.

Comment: Yes, of course you are right. Thanks for the clarification.